# Defining global attributes in XML

Tags: xml, dtd

I think it is a simple question, but after searching I could not find any solution. Is there any way to define global attributes in XML DTD to be accessible by all the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking, can you have a single `ATTLIST` that applies to more than one element, the answer is no. [The attribute list declaration must only have a single name.](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-AttlistDecl) There isn't a way for you to get around having an `ATTLIST` for every element that has attributes.

However, you could use a [parameter entity](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-PE) to reuse attribute definitions in multiple attribute list declarations. This will make it easier to maintain common attributes.

Here's an example. In the example there are two attributes, `attr1` and `attr2`, that are common to elements `elem1` and `elem2`. Those elements also have attributes, `unique-attr1` and `unique-attr2` respectively, that are unique to those elements.

**so.dtd**

```
<!ENTITY % common-attrs
    "common1 CDATA #REQUIRED
     common2 CDATA #REQUIRED">

<!ELEMENT test (elem1,elem2)>

<!ELEMENT elem1 EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST elem1
    %common-attrs;
    unique1 CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT elem2 EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST elem2 
    %common-attrs;
    unique2 CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

Here's an example of what the XML instance would look like:

**so.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE test SYSTEM "so.dtd">
<test>
    <elem1 common1="x" common2="x" unique1="x"/>
    <elem2 common1="x" common2="x" unique2="x"/>
</test>
```

**NOTE:** The use of parameter entity references in markup declaratons, like I'm doing above, is only allowed in the external subset (external DTD); not in the internal subset (internal DTD). (Both the internal and external subsets are discussed in the same section of the spec referenced below.)

From the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-prolog-dtd):

> **Well-formedness constraint: PEs in Internal Subset**
>
> In the internal DTD subset, parameter-entity references must not occur
>   within markup declarations; they may occur where markup declarations
>   can occur. (This does not apply to references that occur in external
>   parameter entities or to the external subset.)

Comment: thanks for the solution. Is this possible to bypass this limitation by using multiple DTD or something like that?

Comment: No I don't see how multiple DTDs would help. Only one DTD could apply at the time of processing. You could split the DTD up into separate files and use parameter entities (with system identifiers) to reference them, but that doesn't achieve what you're trying to achieve; you're just modularizing your DTD.

Comment: Does not work for me. `ATTLIST: no name for Attribute;
internal error: xmlParseInternalSubset: error detected in Markup declaration;
DOCTYPE improperly terminated;
Start tag expected, '<' not found`;

Comment: @Soaku - Sounds like you have a syntax error. You should create a new question with your DTD and the error so we can try to help you get it working.

Comment: @DanielHaley This is weird, because it is what I see when using your example. Well... maybe I missed something? IDK if I really need DTD at the moment, so creating a question might not make sense.

Comment: @Soaku - My answer will not work if you're trying to use it in an internal subset (between `[` and `]` in the doctype declaration). I updated my answer with a note about that. Maybe that's the issue you're seeing? Anyway, thanks for commenting on my answer and helping me to improve it! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an XML Design Pattern : Common Attributes

http://www.xmlpatterns.com/CommonAttributesMain.shtml